# How to create highcharts maps using Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, angularjs-directive, highcharts-ng

I want to create Highcharts maps using Angularjs, how can I do this?
Any directive/library?

thanks

Comment: Hey have you found a way? please share i'm also trying to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't found one but you can easily create a directive by your own. Just create a directiv which is configured like this:

```
.directive('highmap',function($timeout){
    return{
        scope:{ },
        restrict: 'EAC',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
        controller: function($scope, $compile, $attrs, $element){
        }
    }
})
```

Inside the controller you can handle all the map config stuff. Don't forget to set the [render target](http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps#chart.renderTo) to the id of your div.

That's kind of how I am doing it, sadly I am not allowed to share it.

Comment: are you still not allowed  to share? :(  how will the HTML code look like ?